# Post error 404 not found using in-memory Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, in-memory-database

[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-client-crud-in-memory-api-hzdsvd)

I`m trying to create a` in memory services` , but when i tried to post it, it gives a POST ERROR 404 (NOT FOUND). how to fix this one tried to copy the tour of heroes but got this error and i think i got it correctly but its weird that i got the error 404(NOT FOUND).

> IN MEMORY SERVICES

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {

  createDb() {
    const serials = [
  
  {id: 1, deliveryReceiptDetailsId: 0, itemCode:'testing', qtyReceived:0 },
  {id: 2, deliveryReceiptDetailsId: 0, itemCode:'sample1', qtyReceived:0  },
  {id: 3, deliveryReceiptDetailsId: 0, itemCode:'sample2', qtyReceived:0  },
  {id: 4, deliveryReceiptDetailsId: 0, itemCode:'sample3', qtyReceived:0 },
  {id: 5, deliveryReceiptDetailsId: 0, itemCode:'sample4', qtyReceived:0 },
  {id: 6, deliveryReceiptDetailsId: 0, itemCode:'sample5', qtyReceived:0 },
];
console.log(serials)
return {serials};
}
```

> SERVICES

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    'Authorization' : 'my-auth-token'
  })
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SerialCodeService {
  url = 'api/serials';


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<SerialCodeDTO[]> {
    return this.http.get<SerialCodeDTO[]>(this.url)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
  /** POST: add a new hero to the database */
  addHero(serial: SerialCodeDTO): Observable<SerialCodeDTO> {
    return this.http.post<SerialCodeDTO>(this.url, serial, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

Comment: Is your GET call working fine? or just POST is failing?

Comment: both GET and POST failing

Comment: @mishart Could you use this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tour-of-heroes-example) and provide a minimal reproduction of the error and share back?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-client-crud-in-memory-api-hzdsvd @NarenMurali

Answer (score 1):

You had to make sure you register `InMemoryDataService` in forRoot method of `HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule` while importing it in `AppModule`.

```
imports: [
  ...,
  HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
  ...
]
```

Comment: HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService, { 
      dataEncapsulation:false,
    }),

i actually had it